# Generating single KML for multiple geometries in PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a PostgreSQL table which looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE area
(
  area_code character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  shape geometry NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_area PRIMARY KEY (area_code)
)
```

and has an index on the geometry column.

I would like to write a function passing in an array of area_code and returning a single value representing the combined KML for those areas. To return the KML I use [ST_AsKML](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsKML.html). To merge all the areas together I use [ST_UNION](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html). To ensure the union returns a single geometry and not a collection I use [ST_MULTI](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Multi.html). This all gives me:

```
SELECT ST_AsKML(ST_MULTI(ST_UNION(shape))) as KML
FROM area
WHERE area_code = ANY(thearray)
```

When running this in pgAdmin III I get the error:

> ERROR: lwgeom_to_kml2: 'GeometryCollection' geometry type not
>   supported SQL state: XX000 Context: SQL function "st_askml" statement
>   1

but as far as I can see this shouldn't happen. ST_MULTI should ensure that the value being passed to ST_AsKML is not a GeometryCollection. Is my approach correct but needs fixing or am I using entirely the wrong technique to generate the KML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if your `ST_Union` operation produces `Points` or `Linestrings`, for some reason, or if you have a mixture of geometry types in your input to ST_Union, ie, other than Polygons or MultiPolygons. As is stated in the [Google KML docs](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps), `GeometryCollections` are not supported in KML.

You can fix this by calling ST_Union twice, using [ST_Dump](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) to split the unioned geometries apart and only selecting those geometries from the first union (dumped) that produce Polygons or MultiPolygons -- which you can combine without producing a GeometryCollection. You need to use ST_Union twice, as if you use ST_Collect on a Polygon and MultiPolygon, you will get a GeometryCollection again.

```
WITH polygons (geom) as 
   (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Union(shape))).geom 
       FROM area 
       WHERE area_code = any(thearray))
   SELECT ST_AsKML(ST_Multi(ST_Union(geom))) as KML 
       FROM polygons 
       WHERE ST_GeometryType(geom) in ('ST_Polygon','ST_MultiPolygon');
```

You can see the problem with ST_Multi, by running the following query, that attempts to make a Multi geometry out of a Point and a Linestring:

```
SELECT 
   ST_AsText(
       ST_Multi(
         ST_Union(
           ST_MakePoint(0,0),
           ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(5,5), ST_MakePoint(10,10))
         )
      )
 );
```

which returns `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(0 0),LINESTRING(5 5,10 10))`. ST_Multi is not an aggregate function, so essentially just adds Multi and  an extra pair of () to anything that can be made Multi, but will have no impact if you have two types of geometries whose union will force a geometry collection.

**EDIT:** Note the difference between,

```
 SELECT 
   ST_AsText(
     ST_Multi(
       ST_Collect(
         ST_Multi(ST_Expand(ST_MakePoint(0,0),2)),
         ST_Expand(ST_MakePoint(5,5), 1)
      )
   )
);
```

which produces `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(MULTIPOLYGON(((-2 -2,-2 2,2 2,2 -2,-2 -2))),POLYGON((4 4,4 6,6 6,6 4,4 4)))`

and

```
SELECT 
   ST_AsText(
     ST_Multi(
       ST_Union(
         ST_Multi(ST_Expand(ST_MakePoint(0,0),2)),
         ST_Expand(ST_MakePoint(5,5), 1)
      )
   )
);
```

which produces `MULTIPOLYGON(((-2 -2,-2 2,2 2,2 -2,-2 -2)),((4 4,4 6,6 6,6 4,4 4)))`

Because a Polygon can become part of a MultiPolygon, after union, you avoid the dreaded GeometryCollection in the 2nd case. However, if you throw any lines or points into the mix, you will be back in GeomtryCollection land.

**EDIT 2:** Following comments from the OP, the [Google KML docs](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps) state that GeometryCollections are not supported in KML. As there is no way to combine a Point and/or Line with a Polygon without producing a GeometryCollection, the above (Multi)Polygon approach is the only one that will work.

Comment: Thanks. A couple of things. Please edit out the comma from the end of the WHERE area_code = ... line as this shouldn't be there and stops the query working. I can't edit unless I change at least 6 characters. Do you have a link to any documentation stating which GeometryTypes this will work with? Is it just ST_Polygon or will ST_MultiPolygon work? I don't want to throw too much away.

Comment: Thanks, comma removed, I was just writting a whole series of with clauses, so gone a bit comma crazy. Yes, it will work with MultiPolygon too. I also edited the the 2nd query, as you don't need the overhead of  a second ST_Union, you can just use ST_Collect, as after dumping you know that all your (multi) polygons will not overlap.

Comment: Actually, if you are using MultiPolygon and Polygons, then you do need to use ST_Union in 2nd query.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoting as this works. I'd rather not throw away the lines and points, but it's not a show-stopper if I have to. Therefore I'll accept this as the answer tomorrow unless another answer lets me do this for all geographies.

Comment: Andy, I have updated the question a bit. Geometry collections are not supported in KML, as you have discovered, and any combination of different geometry types, (excluding multi (of some type) with same type) will produce a GeometryCollection by definition. If you want to keep the Points/Lines, a possible hack would be to buffer them by a miniscule amount. As KML is mostly for display rather than GIS type analysis (I don't mean that in a negative way), this would probably be acceptable in many cases I would think.

Comment: @AndyNichols, I don't know if you have used GeoJSON before, but that will accept any combination of geometries, unlike KML. If you are using a web mapping client of some kind, Google Maps, OpenLayers, Leaflet, etc, they will all happily digest GeoJSON.

Comment: this particular function will be used to display vectors on a map using OpenLayers3. So there's no reason for me to use KML and I'll try and get GeoJSON working. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You are welcome. You might find this useful for generating featurecollections. postgresonline.com/journal/archives/… I have done a fair bit of work with OpenLayers, Google Maps, Postgres and GeoJSON of late, so happy to answer another question, should you have one :D